# How can I play a mp3 without download from the url?

Tags: android, mp3

I want to develop as follows but I did not find good example:

I want to play without having to download an mp3 encoding in the url.
Unless the user stops it the mp3 should play in the background. 
I guess I do multitasking.

Is there an example document or any advice please.
Thanks.

Comment: very broad question. What should happen if the mp3 is 3 minutes long but  takes 4 minutes to download?

Comment: I don't want to download the mp3, I need to play from an url.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Look at these two tutorials, In these the .mp3 files are playing through web url,

[Example of streaming mp3 mediafile from URL with Android MediaPlayer class](http://www.hrupin.com/2011/02/example-of-streaming-mp3-mediafile-with-android-mediaplayer-class)

[Play Mp3 file from a Url](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Media/PlayMp3filefromaUrl.htm)

Also if you want to play .mp3 file in background I think you have to use Service and AIDL for it,

Look at basic Android-Music Player demo [MusicDroid - Audio Player Part II](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/musicdroid-audio-player-part-ii) it describe how to use Service and AIDl for your Audio Player.

Thanks..

Comment: Does mediaplayer caches the files set with `setDataSource(Context context, Uri uri)`? I'd like to be sure that no new get requests are executed after the initial download

Answer (score 16):

**simple method to do this ::**

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
 mp.setDataSource(PATH_TO_FILE);
 mp.prepare();
 mp.start();
```

Answer (score 8):

```
public class PlayAudioManager {
    private static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

public static void playAudio(final Context context, final String url) throws Exception {
    if (mediaPlayer == null) {
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, Uri.parse(url));
    }
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            killMediaPlayer();
        }
    });
    mediaPlayer.start();
}

private static void killMediaPlayer() {
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        try {
            mediaPlayer.reset();
            mediaPlayer.release();
            mediaPlayer = null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

In your Activity,example,just call
`PlayAudioManager.playAudio(context, http://dict.youdao.com/dictvoice?audio=good&type=1)`

Comment: Please post a little narrative explaining what you did here. Just because the question is vague doesn't mean you should be too.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I had edited my answer,it work for me.

Comment: Your code is fine. My comment refers to the fact that you had no explanation whatsoever.

Answer (score 4):

You can use
 MediaPlayer.create(context, uri);
pass the context(this) and the uri from where you want to play the song

Answer (score 4):

```
if (!isPlaying)
        {
            isPlaying = true;

            mp = new MediaPlayer();

            try {

                mp.reset(); // new one

                mp.setDataSource(AudioPlayer.this, myUri);

                //mp.prepareAsync();

                mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

                mp.prepare(); // don't use prepareAsync for mp3 playback

                mp.start();

                // String songTitle = songsList.get(songIndex).get("songTitle");
                   // songTitleLabel.setText(songTitle);

                songProgressBar.setProgress(0);
                songProgressBar.setMax(100);

                // Updating progress bar
                updateProgressBar();

            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        else
        {
            isPlaying = false; 

            mp.release();// stop Playing 

            //mp = null;
        }
```

I have use it in my MediaPlayer it is working .. there is no need to download it..

Comment: Where do you convert the url to myUri?