# Android Audio not playing from server

Tags: android

I am playing an audio (.mp3) from the server url using the following Android code. But, it is not playing the audio, simply does nothing, no errors. I have set Android min 11 to 22. I am testing on 5.0.2 Android phone. Could someone help what could be the reason not playing, please?

**UPDATED:**

I have solved it now. I converted google drive url to google drive download url using the help this link, and able to play the audio well.
http://www.labnol.org/internet/direct-links-for-google-drive/28356/

Code

```
package com.bclradio.manket.bclfm;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import java.io.IOException;
import android.util.Log;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Context;

public class BCLFMActivity extends Activity {

    final Context context = this;
    static final String AUDIO_PATH =
            "https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzcFuGIeWflwMmlITExmY3BCck0&authuser=0";
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private int playbackPosition=0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bcl_fm);

    }

    public void doClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.PlayStopButton:
                Log.e("FMApp", "Play button clicked");
                //AlertDialog.Builder ab = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                //ab.setMessage("Test").show();
                try {
                    playAudio(AUDIO_PATH);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
        }

    }
    private void playAudio(String url) throws Exception
    {
        killMediaPlayer();
        Log.e("FMApp", "Play Audio function triggered");

        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        killMediaPlayer();
    }

    private void killMediaPlayer() {
        if(mediaPlayer!=null) {
            try {
                mediaPlayer.release();
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_bcl_fm, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Kindly help on this please

Comment: I have solved it finally. I replaced google drive url with the download url using this link, http://www.labnol.org/internet/direct-links-for-google-drive/28356/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at these two tutorials, In these the .mp3 files are playing through web url,

[Example of streaming mp3 mediafile from URL with Android MediaPlayer class](http://www.hrupin.com/2011/02/example-of-streaming-mp3-mediafile-with-android-mediaplayer-class)

[Play Mp3 file from a Url](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Media/PlayMp3filefromaUrl.htm)

Also if you want to play .mp3 file in background I think you have to use Service and AIDL for it,

Look at basic Android-Music Player [demo MusicDroid - Audio Player Part II](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/musicdroid-audio-player-part-ii) it describe how to use Service and AIDl for your Audio Player.

Thanks..

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8486266/3828908) answer.

Comment: I tried playing mp3 from url, but it doesn't play the audio.