# Android MediaPlayer play mp3 from url with bad network

Tags: android, mp3, media-player

I want to play mp3 from url with MediaPlayer, but the network is disconnected when buffering a part of stream, how can I going on buffering the remaining stream when the network connects again.

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse("http://media.cmechina.net/mobile/201500011693/02/flv/5.mp3"));
mp.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener() {

    @Override
    public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
        Log.d("TAG", "percent:  " + percent);
    }
});

mp.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        Log.d("TAG", "onError === what:  " + what + " extra: " + extra);
        return false;
    }
});

mp.setOnInfoListener(new MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        Log.d("TAG", "onInfo   what:  " + what + " extra: " + extra);
        return false;
    }
});

mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        Log.d("TAG", "onCompletion is called!");
    }
});
```

Comment: try this   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8486147/how-can-i-play-a-mp3-without-download-from-the-url

Comment: I know that, but can't help me because I don't find anything about network

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when internet goes down, you should know from onError method, when that happens, you can save the position where the player stopped and try to stream again.
Personally i prefer creating instance from `MediaPlayer` then i use

```
player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
androidPlayer.setDataSource(URL);
androidPlayer.prepareAsync();
```

once the player is ready and triggers `onPrepared(MediaPlayer player)`, check if there is saved position then call `player.seekTo(timeMilisecond)`

remember to set listener for `onPrepared` and on `onSeekComplete`

Answer (score 0):

i have the same problem, but in my case i got no onError call (yes it's registered) but after playing the already buffered data i got an onComplete call.